# linear regression on log-log histogram in numpy

Tags: numpy, histogram, linear-regression

I have a distribution (drawn with numpy.histogram) that seems to be linear when plotted on log-log axis. I'd like to compute and draw a linear regression on this histogram to find out the parameters of the linear regression, as well as the r square.

I've tried different things (using polyfit on the values returned by numpy.histogram), looked around quite a bit but, although this is probably a very common problem, I can't seem to find a simple method to do this. Is there any?

Comment: Did you try good old `numpy.linalg.lstsq`? `coef = lstsq(x, y)[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you fit a line to the log of the values?

```
log y = a log x + b (fit a and b)
=> y = x^a e^b
```

Comment: No I can't, and I suspect that is because I have a few zeros on the y axis. np.polyfit probably doesn't like dealing with values like np.log(0)=-inf...

Comment: So some bins in the histogram have count 0? This means that eg all models have infinite r^2. What if you fit to the data ignoring the 0 bins?